# How to open my application in android device when i click home or back button

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi Friends i did one application..its every thing got over and i uploded in market..but my problem is once user downloaded my application means then when  user click home button or back button  means always  need to open my application directly..is it possible means can you please any one give me idea..

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

 @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();
        this.getWindow().setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_KEYGUARD);           
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go and see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html for registering that back key was pressed in the background.(Not sure if it will work, go try yourself). And about the HOME key. It's handled by framework so normal apps can't access it.